# What's the purpose of nesting a \def within a \newcommand?

Tags: macros

I recently found the following piece of code:

```
\newcommand{\ISBN}[1]{\def\ISBN{#1}}
```

Isn't it redundant? What's its purpose?

---

**UPDATE**
I now understand its purpose. I have never seen it before. Is it common? Are there other ways of accomplishing the same effect---using a macro to assign a value to the very macro? (For the sake of it, I tried it in Python, which is dynamically typed, but it doesn't work as in LaTeX: `def ISBN(value): ISBN = value`.)

Comment: I found a case where `\newcommand{\ISBN}[1]{\def\@ISBN{#1}}` was used. Without *any* difference between the csnames (like the @), the only way I can think of returning the value later is with `\meaning`. I think this is typically used in writing classes. So the idea with that is that the user defines ISBN by calling the so-named macro (which is tidier than `\def\@ISBN{..}`. And the class stores it (@ISBN) and applies it, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may provide an unconditional setting of content that has a one-time use. Consider the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% ==============================================

% These is defined inside some class/style file
\newcommand{\booktitle}[1]{\def\booktitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\bookauthor}[1]{\def\bookauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\ISBN}[1]{\def\ISBN{#1}}

% ==============================================

\booktitle{My title}
\bookauthor{The author}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

Book title: \booktitle{}

Book author: \bookauthor{}

ISBN: \ISBN{}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, the user only supplied a `\booktitle` and `\bookauthor`, but not an `\ISBN`. However, if we supply an empty argument to each macro when we use it in the document body, it displays as empty or whatever was supplied by the user.

---

A more common use is typically seen with titles, where

```
\newcommand{\title}[1]{\def\@title{#1}}
\newcommand{\author}[1]{\def\@author{#1}}
```

so there is internal access to `\@title` and `\@author`. Additionally, one can test whether the user supplied some `\title{<title>}` and/or `\author{<author>}` by checking whether or not `\@title`/`\@author` exists using (say) `\@ifundefined`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any sensible usage for such a strategy. Calling `\ISBN` without the braces would gobble the `\par` token, in your example; in any case it would gobble the following spaces and the next token or braced group. It is just bad programming, if written that way.

Comment: @egreg: The idea is not to let the user call `\ISBN` *without* brackets. They would call (say) `\ISBN{<isbn>}` and then later use `\maketitle` (or something) that would set `\ISBN{}`. Either way, this is a speculative usage of why that definition may exist in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, but is a very bad idea nonetheless. Calling `\ISBN{whatever}` in the document body would do absolutely nothing the first time and have a puzzling effect the next time.

Comment: @egreg: If described properly in a user manual, I don't see a problem with it. Using `\title` in the document body does absolutely nothing the first time, and using it a second time after `\maketitle` is a truly puzzling effect...

Answer (score 6):

Does it really have that? I couldn't find any instances via google except for this question. some journal classes, eg `jss.cls` have

```
\newcommand{\ISBN}[1]{\def\@ISBN{#1}}
```

which is much more reasonable, and I expect (hope!) the code you found was intended to be of that form, and is an error in the class.

As shown, it's legal as Werner explains but it is a terrible user interface. Not because the command is redefined, but because it is redefined with a different argument structure, so the command takes a different syntax depending on whether it has been previously used, which is a poor design even if it works as intended.

There are uses for self-defining macros for example the following which makes a list defining itself to add a comma separator after the first use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo{\theenumi\def\foo{\refstepcounter{enumi}, \theenumi}}


\begin{document}

 like this {\foo}

 or this {\foo\foo\foo}

 or this {\foo}

 or this {\foo\foo\foo}

\end{document}
```

Note there is nothing too special about `\def` inside `\newcommand`: the same could be done with `\def` inside `\def` or `\renewcommand` inside `\newcommand` but of the three `\def` inside `\newcommand` is probably preferable as you check the top level command isn't clashing with another package, but you omit the checks on the inner definition which you know is *always* a re-definition.

Comment: Take a look at lines 545--551 of the file at https://github.com/Arkq/calibre-latex/blob/master/tex_output.py. (It's a script which converts .epub into .tex, using the Calibre programme.)

Comment: @NVaughan :-) I didn't disbelieve you had found such code. As I say it would be a pretty terrible user interface but if this is just generated code used to typeset stuff and no human is actually having to write it, such a concern is not relevant.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I reckon that the `@` trick should have been better practice anyway.